# Convert string representation of a list to a list in Java

Tags: java

Is there any easy, one (not too complicated) line for this?

If we have `List<String> li1 = Arrays.asList("a","b");`, then `li1.toString()` will yield `[a, b]`. So how to convert string `[a, b]` to a list of strings?

Connected with it is the question why produced string isn't `["a","b"]`? Because from string representations we cannot distinguish `Arrays.asList("1","2","3")` from `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)`. And also it's not possible to parse produced string with e.g. Jackson with `objectMapper.readValue(li1.toString(), String[].class);`, which would be that one line solution.

Comment: toString isn't meant for serilization. I'm sure Java has some other standard way of doing that.

Comment: so basically you want to serialize an array and deserialize them back out of the box? out of the box we got [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).. but it turns to binary.

Comment: What if your original list is `Arrays.asList("a, b", "c")`?

Comment: Is the question "how to properly serialize/deserialize an array (preferrably in human readable form)", or "am I correct that it's not possible to deserialize a list's toString form back to the original list"?

Comment: "it's not possible to parse produced string with e.g. Jackson " - that's because `toString()` _does not_ produce valid json which jackson will need to parse the string correctly.

Comment: So the target is to convert string to array of string if it is representation of a list.toString() ??

Comment: The Arrays.toString () method is written that way only. So it is going to print the content seprated by comma.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, I hoped there is an easy way to do fromString/toString for collections, without any additional serialization methods. Something I overlooked. Just like there is Integer.parseInt(). Andy great example, additional reason why still don't understand how [a, b] is better than ["a", "b"], no matter is it json or not.

Comment: `[a, b]` is not better in any way. The folks at Java simply decided that `"foo".toString() == "foo"` and not `"\"foo\""`, which is good for reading but bad for parsing. For this reason, Python has two methods: `str` and `repr`.

Comment: Instead of toString() use objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);.

Comment: @SangamBelose Yes, already switched to that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how to convert string [a, b] to a list of strings?

It is not intended for this purpose.

> Connected with it is the question why produced string isn't ["a","b"]? Because from string representations we cannot distinguish Arrays.asList("1","2","3") from Arrays.asList(1,2,3).

This has probably to tdo with the following: `Arrays.toString()` just concatenates the string representations of the items with `,` separator and puts `[]` around it. So the real answer is "because string `"1"` and integer `1` have the same representation". And this, again, has to do with the fact that both should be printable as they are. E. g., Python differentiates between `__str__()` and `__repr()__`, Java has only `.toString()`.

But as the `.toString()` outputs are (apart from certain special cases) only made for debugging, it should not matter.

> And also it's not possible to parse produced string with e.g. Jackson with objectMapper.readValue(li1.toString(), String[].class);, which would be that one line solution.

If you want to do that, there are other solutions which are far better suitable for sertializtion and deserialization.

Formats for serialization are

- binary
- XML
- JSON

all of which are made of a pair of unambiguous serialized data creation and deserialization which does the opposite.

Comment: This is the most complete answer. And understand now better why using quotes wouldn't be a good idea. Class could be defined as `class X{ public String toString() { return "1"; } }`, so it's neither string or number, and using ["1"] over [1] doesn't make sense. And using quotes for list elements would be also bad if those elements are lists themselves.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggested, it's not a good idea to do that. But to still give an answer to your question:

> how to convert string [a, b] to a list of strings?

```
String s = "[a, b]";

//remove first and last character and create array of Strings splitting around the characters ", "
String[] strings = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(",");

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);
System.out.println(list);
```

Note that if one of your strings in the list contains a comma, this will not work, but there is no way to handle this case.

---

Or you could use [org.springframework.util.StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#commaDelimitedListToStringArray(java.lang.String)) but it will keep the leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this Spring method. But it doesn't work out of the box as [ and ] must be stripped first. Guess the easiest way is to combine it with `collectionToDelimitedString(Collection<?> coll,                                                String delim)`. These two don't have to deal with exceptions like Jackson methods. And first part is ok, but not really a one liner :)

Comment: @VukDjapic : exactly, we used both methods in a project where we wanted to store a list as a string in a database to prevent us for creating a useless new table

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways how to do it, but I don't think there is any method how to make it directly.
And Its also not a good idea to deal with `toString()` as you are trying (it can be overriden, eg.)

One of possible solutions can be like follows:

```
public static List<String> getListFromListStringArray(String inString){
    List<String> returnList = null;

    System.out.println("in: " + inString);

    /*
     * Will remove leading and trailing [ ]
     * [a, b] => a, b 
     */
    inString = inString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
    /* 
     * Will create List from String array by delimiter (, ) in this case 
     */
    returnList = Arrays.asList(inString.split(", "));
    //[a, b]
    System.out.println(returnList.toString());

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the toString for serialization /deserialization.

Instead of that you should convert it into string as below:

```
 String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);

// To convert it back into string array

objectMapper.readValue(str, String[].class);
```